# How to make Solr search in Case insensitive?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, case-insensitive, solr4

I use apache **solr 8.7** Version.

This is my managed-schema code for **case insensitive** search. But it not properly worked.

```
 <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
        />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>

      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
        />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

this is some recordes of my database.

[image]

I hope help to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have examples of what's not working? Since you have the LowercaseFilterFactory, standard english should be lowercased and your search should be case insensitive. What does the analysis page for the field show with the given indexed text (the text in the field in the document) and your search query?

Comment: quality:low*   This is my query . But it actually included "Low".It cannot search any documents

Comment: Wildcard searches are special; they are not processed by every filter in your analysis chain (only those that are multiterm aware, which in this case probably only means the lowercasefilter). What does `quality:low` give you? (without the wildcard)

Comment: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1103,
    "params":{
      "q":"quality:low",
      "_":"1613987836745"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  }}

Comment: without wildcard, it gives output like this.

Comment: This is where the Analysis page comes into play; it'll give you exactly how the text is processed when indexing and when searching, and will show which tokens are generated on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to search only on "quality" field, the above field type definition seems over-engineered to me and hence resulting in unintended results.

I would suggest start with minimum needed field type definition like the following and then keep adding as per requirements like Stemming or Alphanumeric or Synonym search:

```
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>

      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

This is a bottom up approach and it works best when you are working with something new and with lot of unknown variables.

Every filterfactory in the question has a specific purpose, so use only if you have a requirement for it.

All solr filter factories: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_5/filter-descriptions.html